# Java exit a program without quitting JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I want to exit a java process and free all the resources before it finishes its normal running, if a certain condition is meet. I dont however want to quit JVM, as I have other java programs running at the same time. Does `return;` do the above, or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@aix's answer is probably apropos to your question.  Each time you run the `java` command (or the equivalent) you get a different JVM instance.  Calling `System.exit()` in one JVM instance won't cause other JVM instances to exit.  (Try it and see!)

It *is possible* to create a framework in which you do run multiple programs within the same JVM.  Indeed this is effectively what you do when you run a "bean shell".  The same sort of thing happens when your "programs" are services (or webapps, or whatever you call them) running in some application server framework.

The bad news is that if you do this kind of thing, there is no entirely reliable way make an individual "program" go away.  In particular, if the program is not designed to be cooperative (e.g. if it doesn't check for interrupts), you will have to resort to the DEPRECATED `Thread.stop()` method and friends.  And those methods can have nasty consequences for the JVM and the other programs running in it.

In theory, the solution to that problem is to use Isolates.  Unfortunately, I don't think that any mainstream JVMs support Isolates.

Comment: yeah, for now I just start them separately, tho it eats up a lot more RAM now. In a multithreaded system you could do `join()`, but not sure what to do with this one besides separate startups.

Comment: Doing a `join()` only works if the "program" is cooperating; e.g. regularly checking to see if it has been interrupted.

Answer (score 9):

There is one JVM process per running Java application. If you exit that application, the process's JVM gets shut down. However, this does not affect other Java processes.

Comment: I start them as services under Debian linux & it seems that if I `System.exit();` one of them, the rest will quit as well... I may have to start them on boot as separate java programs.. will try that now. Thanks for a quick reply. Tho, what effect will `return;` make on the running program?

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand the JVM mechanism and clarify the terminology.

Let's use the following as datum for the terminology.

- Threads are divisions of concurrently processed flows within a process.
- A process is an OS level thread. The OS manages the processes. A process is terminated by sending a termination signal to the OS management. The signal may be sent by the process itself or by another process that has the applicable privilege.
- Within a process, you can create process level threads. Process level threads are normally facilitated by the process management of the OS, but they are initiated by the process and terminated by the process. Therefore, process level threads are not the same as processes.
- An application is a collection of systems, programs and/or threads that cooperate in various forms. A program or process within an application may terminate without terminating the whole application.

Within the context of JVM terminology, program may be one of the following.

- A program is run per JVM process. Each program consumes one JVM process and is invoked by supplying the classpath of java bytecode and specifying the main entry point found in the classpath. When you terminate a java program, the whole jvm process that ran that program also terminates.
- A program is run per process level thread. For example, an application run within a tomcat or JEE server is run as a thread within the JEE process. The JEE process is itself a program consuming one JVM process. When you terminate an application program, the JEE process does not terminate.

You may initiate process level threads within a java program. You may write code that terminates a thread but that would not terminate the process (unless it is the last and only running thread in the process). The JVM garbage collection would take care of freeing of resources and you do not need to free resources yourself after a process level thread is terminated.

The above response is simplified for comprehension. Please read up on OS design and threading to facilitate a better understanding of processes and the JVM mechanism.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I need to read up on threading / server architecture and OS design in general, - I didnt know that starting java program separately would create separate JVM's... I would prefer to start them in one JVM to save some RAM, but its a job for another day. Guess Ill be rewiring these particular programs, when I have a better understanding of how they should work and how I should terminate a thread(?) without terminating all of them.

Answer (score 3):

If the other threads running concurrently are not daemon threads, leaving `main` will not terminate the VM. The other threads will continue running.

I completely missed the point though.

If you start each program in a separate JVM, calling `System.exit()` in one of them will not influence the others, they're entirely different processes.

If you're starting them through a single script or something, depending on how it is written, something else could be killing the other processes. Without precise information about how you start these apps, there's really no telling what is going on.

Comment: yes, thats true, thanks. I dont run them as threads, these are separate programs, started as service @ boot.. they seem to all exit at the same time tho.. see above.

Comment: They were started by the same service (another java program) --> seemed like all were running in the same JVM. Just made a script to start them separately @ boot and it works as expected. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Some common usecases leading these kind of requirements can be solved through tools like Nailgun, or Drip.

[Nailgun](https://github.com/facebook/nailgun) allows you to run what appears to be multiple independent executions of a commandline program, but they all happen in the same JVM. Therefore repeated JVM start-up time does not have to be endured. If these execution interact with global state, then the JVM will get polluted in time and things start to break up.

[Drip](https://github.com/ninjudd/drip) will use a new JVM for each execution, but it always keeps a precreated JVM with the correct classpath and options ready. This is less performant, but it can guarantee correctness through isolation.